# Magento Cron file inclusion error

Tags: magento, cron

I have first time installed th cron job for magento.
THere is one module that has a cronjob setup like following in config.xml

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <campaigns_observer_discount>
            <!-- each 7 minutes -->
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>campaigns/observer::discountExpiryAlert</model></run>
        </campaigns_observer_discount>

    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

When cron.php runs the magento is looking for file under mage directory not in local folder
the error states as follows

```
2011-08-12T13:38:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Campaigns/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/website/src/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

It should look for **Namespace/Campaigns/Model/Observer.php** . I tried to change the parameter in config.xml

```
<run><model>namespace_campaigns/observer::discountExpiryAlert</model></run>
```

then magento looks for file **Mage/Namespace/Campaigns/Model/Observer.php**

Can any body suggest me where I am going wrong? THanks, ur help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento doesn't know your "Namespace" and automatically prepends Mage therefore. There is another error in your config.xml, most likely in the global/model part:

```
<models>
    <campaigns>
        <class>Namespace_Campaigns_Model</class>
    </campaigns>
</models>
```

should be the correct definition according to your sample code above.

Comment: We need some standard terminology in the Magento community.  I never know whether to call it a namespace, class prefix, etc.

Comment: @bami.c man u were 100% right. I added this cron to the existing module. but never looked that if models are correctly configured. now its works. Many thanks.